# How to detect moving of an item between knockout observable arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, knockout.js

I am building a web-abb using query and knockout.
On a certain page I have a couple of lists of items.
These lists are sortable and connected, so as far as JQuery goes all is working OK. I have used Ryan Niemeyer's example to create a custom binding for the sortables to update my view-model's observable arrays.

This works all quite nicely but i want to save the changes to a back-end server.
Using subscriptions on the observable arrays i can detect that an item is removed from, and is added to the array but this leads to two update calls to the back-end server.

If something goes wrong during one of these calls then the backend will be in an invalid state.

How would one go about detecting that the removal of an item and subsequent adding of that same item so that the web-application can make one move-call to the back-end server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that a good way to handle this would be to add a callback option to the sortableList binding that passes the item, original parent, and new parent as arguments.

Here is what the binding that I am using for KO 2.0 might look like with a callback:

```
//connect items with observableArrays
ko.bindingHandlers.sortableList = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, data, context) {
        var options = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());

        //attach the appropriate class to our element
        if (ko.bindingHandlers.sortableList.autoAddClass) {
             ko.utils.toggleDomNodeCssClass(element, ko.bindingHandlers.sortableList.defaultClass, true);   
        }

        $(element).data("sortList", options.list || valueAccessor()); //attach meta-data
        $(element).sortable({
            update: function(event, ui) {
                var item = ui.item.data("sortItem");
                if (item) {
                    //identify parents
                    var originalParent = ui.item.data("parentList");
                    var newParent = ui.item.parent().data("sortList");
                    //figure out its new position
                    var position = ko.utils.arrayIndexOf(ui.item.parent().children(), ui.item[0]);
                    if (position >= 0) {
                        originalParent.remove(item);
                        newParent.splice(position, 0, item);
                    }
                    ui.item.remove();

                    if (options.afterDrop) {
                       options.afterDrop.call(this, item, newParent, originalParent);   
                    }
                }
            },
            connectWith: '.' + ko.bindingHandlers.sortableList.defaultClass
        });
        return ko.bindingHandlers.template.init.apply(this, arguments);
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, data, context) {
       var options = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()),
           newOptions = {}; 

        //build our options to pass to the template engine
        if (options.list) {
            newOptions.foreach = options.list;
            newOptions.name = options.tmpl;
            newOptions.includeDestroyed = options.includeDestroyed;
            newOptions.afterAdd = options.afterAdd;
            newOptions.beforeRemove = options.beforeRemove; 
        } else {
           newOptions.foreach = valueAccessor();
        }

        //use an afterRender function to add meta-data
        if (options.afterRender) {
            //wrap the existing function, if it was passed
            newOptions.afterRender = function(element, data) {
               ko.bindingHandlers.sortableList.afterRender.call(data, element, data);
               options.afterRender.call(data, element, data); 
            }  
        } else {
            newOptions.afterRender = ko.bindingHandlers.sortableList.afterRender;
        }
        //call the actual template binding
        ko.bindingHandlers.template.update(element, function() { return newOptions; }, allBindingsAccessor, data, context);  
    },
    afterRender: function(elements, data) {
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(elements, function(element) {
            if (element.nodeType === 1) {
                $(element).data("sortItem", data);
                $(element).data("parentList", $(element).parent().data("sortList"));
            } 
        });
    },
    defaultClass: 'container',
    autoAddClass: true
};
```

You would then specify the binding like:

```
<ul data-bind="sortableList: { tmpl: 'myItems', list: myObservableArray, afterDrop: myCallback }"></ul>
```

Now, you can add your own callback that tells the server that the item was moved.   observableArrays are functions (which are objects), so you can actually assign properties to them.  Here is a sample where I assigned an `id` property to each observable array and then access it in the callback, so that I have a friendly way of knowing which one was the old parent and which was the new parent:

http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/QZscP/

Comment: Thanx Ryan, using your example I implemented something similar. It needed some extra functionality because in my app there can be multiple reasons an item is added or removed. Btw, your posts about knockout are really great, I use them very often! Don't think I would use knockout as much as I do without them.

Comment: @RogierBessem I recently cleaned this up a bit and created a project for it here: https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-sortable.  Maybe the newer version might work for you or certainly if you have feedback feel free to share.  Thanks!